# How do I kill a process in Ubuntu knowing part of the command used to start it?

Tags: process

Basically, if I start a process with the command "./process arg1 arg2 89sudfjKSDf" and know that "89sudfjKSDf" is part of the command, how can I kill all processes that contain "89sudfjKSDf" in their command name? So far it's been looking it up in "ps aux" and finding that identifier, but now I want to automate it in a script.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in a bash script

```
#!\bin\bash
ps -ef | grep '89sudfjKSDf' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: I don't remember if "-ef" works in Ubuntu, but that can be addressed relatively easily